# Как получить ll = долготу и широту места, на которые кликнули мышью, зная масштаб z и центр карты ll, используя static api

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как получить ll = долготу и широту места, на которые кликнули мышью, зная масштаб z и центр карты ll, используя static api

Answer (score 1):

Static API отдаёт вам растровое изображение карты, сгенеренное по заданным параметрам. Каких-то методов для дальнейшего взаимодействия с этим изображением в API нет (на то оно и Static).

В JS API географические координаты щелчка отдаются в поле coords события [MapEvent](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/MapEvent.html):

```
map.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var position = e.get('coords');
});
```

Пример есть [тут](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode).

Comment: Можно ли реализовать на python?

Comment: @GribIvan Сейчас речь идёт о JavaScript API. Что именно вы хотите реализовать на пайтоне, какая глобальная задача?